# Transparently bypass proxy to access to certain domains over SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

I'm working in a setup of a big company that has dozens of firewalls and a big proxy server. From time to time I need to access some services that are in isolated networks and I have access to the services in that networks. Currently I have the following approach:

1. I have an app where I configure local tunnels e.g.

   ```
   ssh -L 30001:super01.secret.host:3419 secretServer1
   ssh -L 30002:super01.secret.host:8080 secretServer1
   ssh -L 30011:super02.secret.host:8080 secretServer1
   ssh -L 30021:super03.secret.host:4000 secretServer2
   ```
2. I have bookmarks for each web service that point to (for example) localhost:30001
3. I configure the local programs that I develop to use the localhost:30001 urls.

I know that there is another way with dynamic port forwarding and Socks proxy, but it's a real pain to configure it (considering that I have to have anyway a system-wide proxy of my company).

Is there a way to redirect requests that go to super01.secret.host:3419 and route them via the localhost:30001? Because then I can implement an app (script) where you define that you want to access super01.secret.host via the secretServer1 server and it will open a local port forwarding and create a redirection. Or is there an even nicer way to configure this.

My main goal:
- have all the networking setup system-wide
- have a transparent access to the services from the isolated networks (i.e. if from that network I have to access super01.secret.host:8080 I want to get an access to the same host and port from my local machine)
- I want to make all the rest of the networking to work as before (i.e. the requests are routed through the company's proxy unless they are in the noproxy list)

Answer (score 0):

You may use both ssh proxies and port fowarding using iptables

1. you set up ssh proxies, like you do.
2. port forwarding, eg. for the first redirection

   ```
   iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp -d secretServer1 --dport 3419 -j DNAT --to localhost:3001
   ```

**Note** : this has not been tested